# FTP file using WINSCP console by running a batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp, winscp

I tried by running the following batch script:-

```
"C:\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /console /command "option batch on" "open apps:apps@10.240.2.191"  "cd /data/ftp/John"  "lcd E:\ERP Attend " "put Attend_*.csv" "close" "exit"
```

But the problem is

In lcd path there is a space in the folder "E:\ERP Attend" due to which it is unable to read the path.

Please help me in executing the script without eliminating the space.There must be a way out to bypass the space I guess.

Comment: I.e. `"lcd ""E:\ERP Attendance"""`

Comment: See [WinSCP documentation on command-line syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax).